# how to insert multiple row after getting last inserted row id

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to insert some data into a table (one row) then after this ended , I want to insert some rows into other table B which is related to table A with A_id . So I want to get current row id of table A I have inserted data then use it to put data into other table.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (titleA)
  VALUES('test title A')


for ($i=0 ; $i<9 ; $i++){
INSERT INTO b_shop_option (titleB,A_id) VALUES ('$title[$i]',LAST_INSERT_ID())
}
```

last inserted id is changing every second.so it doesn't work for my required A_id

Comment: Can you please post actual code ?

Comment: You understand `LAST_INSERT_ID()` wil become the new inserted ID in your loop ? Save this value inside a value before the loop, and use your variable.

Answer (score -1):

You should try like as below example

```
   $q1 = INSERT INTO tableA (titleA)
  VALUES('? ?');
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", 'test', 'Title A');

$q1_last_inserted_id = $your_conncetion_variable->lastInsertId();

for ($i=0 ; $i<9 ; $i++){
INSERT INTO b_shop_option (titleB,A_id) VALUES ('$title[$i]',$q1_last_inserted_id)
}
```

Comment: if you are using SQL injection, then you can use login like this